# ООП в чем отличие паттерна activerecord и ORM?

Tags: php, ооп

ООП в чем отличие паттерна activerecord и ORM ?

Answer (score 6):

Вопрос сформулирован неверно.

AR - это и есть ORM, один из вариантов реализации.
То есть вопрос звучит как "чем отличается мерседес от автомобиля".

Если говорить о каких-то различиях, то обычно имеются в виду два варианта реализации ORM - Active Record и Data Mapper. Отличаются они только тем, что в AR методы работы с БД хранятся в самом объекте, а в DM - отдельно. Вследствие чего последний считается более академически правильным (разделение ответственности) и дает больше преимуществ в сложных проектах. Примерами реализации AR являются Yii AR и Eloquent, DM - Doctrine и Atlas.Orm.